# How can custom tooltips be used with excel charts using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to create custom pop up displays on a chart using vba.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPq61.png) except instad of "Value: 6" display the corresponding comment. "Yes"

[Here](http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2010/12/better-chart-tooltips-with-microsoft-excel-2010.html) is an article with an example workbook that shows a textbox when hovering over a point on the chart. The explanations on the website are not detailed enough for me to understand what is going on. When I try and modify the example workbook it stops functioning.

Is there a method to tracing excel vba code to discover what it is doing? Or, is there a better simple method for creating custom tooltips with excel charts?

Thanks.

Comment: *Is there a method to tracing excel vba code to discover what it is doing?*  **Yes**. Step through the code using F8 in debug mode, use the Locals window to examine variables/objects, use the Immediate window to test lines of code as executable, and other common debugging techniques can help you "reverse-engineer" someone else's code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a chart (as a new sheet, not an embedded chart) and editing the VBA code for the sheet to:

```
Private Sub Chart_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
Dim ElementID As Long
Dim Arg1 As Long
Dim Arg2 As Long
Dim chart_data As Variant
Dim chart_label As Variant
Dim last_bar As Long
Dim chrt As Chart
Dim ser As Series

On Error Resume Next

Me.GetChartElement x, y, ElementID, Arg1, Arg2

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set chrt = ActiveChart
Set ser = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
Set ser2 = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2)
chart_data1 = ser.Values
chart_label1 = ser.XValues
chart_data2 = ser2.Values
chart_label2 = ser2.XValues
Set txtbox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("hover")

If ElementID = xlSeries Then
    If Err.Number Then
        Set txtbox = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox _
                                        (msoTextOrientationHorizontal, x, y, 400, 120) 'Textbox size
        txtbox.Name = "hover"
        txtbox.Fill.Solid
        txtbox.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 9
        txtbox.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
        chrt.Shapes("hover").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Insert text wanted to display here"
        With chrt.Shapes("hover").TextFrame.Characters.Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 14
            .ColorIndex = 16
        End With
        last_bar = Arg2
    End If
    ser.Points(Arg2).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    txtbox.Left = 0 'textbox location
    txtbox.Top = 0 'textbox location

Else
    txtbox.Delete
    ser.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This created a textbox when the mouse movement was over an Element of "xlSeries".